# Identify duplicate records in rows

Tags: sql, duplicates, record

The table of information is following:

```
ID   Period   Deposit_amount   Flag
10   201001   2000             1
10   201002   2000             1
10   201003   1000             1
10   201204   7000             0
10   201205   7000             0
```

In this table contain the information of deposit amount from customer in each month, I decide to put flag to the amount of money that `<4000 (1)` and amount `>=4000 (0)` ,you can see that period `201001 - 201003` have flag of 1 in 3 month in a row.

Please help me to identify the group of duplicate record in this 3 record in a row.

Comment: I don't know about the others, but I don't get what you want. What do you mean by "duplicate records in this 3 record in a row"?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well, you want to find duplicate row where Flag = 1 ?
Something like that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM your_table_name A
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM your_table_name B
    WHERE A.ID <> B.ID AND Flag = 1 AND A.Deposit_amount = B.Deposit_amount
)
```

You can change the sql to fit your needs ...
I hope your ID aren't all the same because that wouldn't works.